# Количество элементов listtview

Tags: android

Привет, требуется чтобы при выводе  в listview было видно и скроллилось по 3 пункта списка (всего 20)

Comment: Необходимо конректизировать вопрос, т.к. не совсем понятно, какой UX ожидается в результате

Comment: Парсится информация с сервера и выводится в listview. На сервере 20 файлов, в listview должны показываться не все элементы сразу, а заданное количество - 3. Т.е скролл по 3 пункта.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду постраничную загрузку по три элемента в тот момент, когда пользователь долистает до конца текущего списка?

Comment: Да, именно это..

Comment: Хорошо, я понял, но не могу помочь вам. Судя по тому, как вы слабы в терминологии (не обижайтесь), вы скорее всего ищете простой пример, а в своих проектах я обладаю очень сложными с привлечением сторонних библиотек. Отредактируйте свой вопрос согласно вашим ответам, которые вы мне дали, так на него быстрее ответят. Используйте термин "Пагинация" - именно так называется требующийся вам механизм подгрузки. Пока ждете ответ, можете гуглить "listview pagination android", в топе сразу будут несколько вопросов, похожих на ваш. Удачи!